# PHP modules don't load after installing PHP 7 to my server

Tags: php, curl, ini, php-extension, ubuntu-server

I installed PHP 7 to my server (as a result, I have not /etc/php5 and /etc/php/7.0). When I run my web app, I cant see any of my previous CURL (or fork).

at first I got this err msg:

> Message: Call to undefined function curl_init()

and after installing php7-curl i get it enabled - approved on info() function and this test code:

```
var_dump(_isCurl());
function _isCurl(){
    return function_exists('curl_version');
}
```

returning TRUE.

but when having an actual CURL in my code I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

in `/usr/lib/php/20151012/` i have only `.so` files which doesn't make sense. (same goes for the `/usr/lib/php5/20131226` folder). So what is it trying to get and why from  there?

how can I configure my new php.ini file to get the previous model settings? (if possible with the enabled PCNTL_FORK too) How can I make it work with curl? what the hell happened???

**EDIT 04.05.2016:**

Ok, i decided to change it to `curl.so` and now got this msg `PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0` and then I disabled it, and somehow, curl now is working (commented curl `;extension:curl.so` and `;extension:php_curl.dll`. 
What the hell.

Comment: Do you want to have both versions at the same time?

Comment: well, no, but I do want to keep the old settings from  the php.ini :X.

Comment: Is this what you're going to suggest? 
`root@YHserver:/usr/lib/php5/20131226# sudo a2dismod php5
Module php5 already disabled` 

doesn't work...

Comment: Having a .dll (windows!) file on a linux server doesn't make sense. Change the php_curl.dll to curl.so (or php_curl.so, whatever the file is called) and try again

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything. Your question states *I have not /etc/php5 and /etc/php/7.0* which is rather confusing and you appear to be loading libraries from different versions. I simply didn't know what you were trying to do.

Comment: you have to change the file reference from .dll to .so. Moreover, i had the same problem and i had to delete the php module and reinstall them, because i had some of them in php5.6 (and it wasn't detected automatically).

Comment: @Unex so what do you suggest doing? completly remove php7 and install it again (`sudo apt-get --purge remove ...` )?

Comment: run phpinfo() and see what is installed.

Comment: no php7 is probably ok. Just remove the curl extension and install the new version. Apt-get probably didn't get that version mismatched.

Comment: Ok, i decided to change it to `curl.so` and now got this msg `PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0` and then I disabled it, and somehow, curl now is working (commented curl `;extension:curl.so` and `;extension:php_curl.dll`. 
What the hell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

running `apt-get dist-upgrade` fixed all the problems  :)

Comment: Wow it works for me too, I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS , I use the above comand with sudo. thank.

Answer (score 15):

I had this exact problem.

I have just spent the last few hours trying to fix some stuff and in my haste I for some reason enabled this line:

```
extension:php_curl.dll
```

Obviously, that makes 0 sense, as someone said but the error message is weird after you do that. Running `apt-get dist-upgrade` DID NOT solve the problem.

So, after pulling out some more hair and re-reading this post a 100 times,
I just commented it back out

```
;extension:php_curl.dll
```

and ya, problem solved.

So the OP must have done what I did... drink beer while working

Comment: Same happend to me :p

Answer (score 3):

On my case, to get curl working :

- sudo apt-get install php-curl
- comment curl extension : `;extension=php_curl.dll` in php.ini (eg /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini)

Answer (score 0):

Settings might get mixed up when two versions of PHP being installed at the same time -- for example, 7.0 and 7.3. This can be because a recent dist-upgrade. The wrong version of the module might get loaded. In my case, apt purge php7.0 and a reinstall of 7.3 fixed me up, of course you might not want to be as heavy-handed with your own system...